# How to print a new message while keep the words that you typed?

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to write a Linux command line chat room client.

I want to split the command window to different parts: input, chat, rooms, status like [this one](http://lifehacker.com/5861211/centerim-is-a-linux-command-line-chat-program).

How can I print the new message from the server to the chat part of the window while keeping the other parts of the window?

Right now, the client that I have written is quite simple, it print all message to `stdout`, so it will ruin the words that you typed.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). It's a standard component in virtually all Linux distros and well documented (it even comes with a full set of man pages for all routines; for example, the `man 3 printw` command shows the documentation of the `printw()` function). It's also easy to use. You create several "windows" on the screen and can write text anywhere you like using x/y coordinates. They're not real windows, of course, since this is a text terminal; an ncurses window is just an area of the terminal.

For a nice introduction, see the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).